# vim localleader and whitespace

Tags: vim

I've just binded `localleader` to " " (the space button) and now vim slows down every time I press space. I guess it waits for some combination but I don't have any bindings in insert mode which uses `localleader` key. Are there any way to tell vim not to wait after `localleader` key in insert mode?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you sure you don't have any insert-mode mappings? Is `:verbose imap <Space>` empty?

Comment: Sorry, it was snippmate. Couldn't find it because it was assigned using `let` rather than ~map... Thanks for pointing me out.

Comment: Ah, great. I've added an answer.

Comment: Can also be good to know that you can reset `maplocalleader` after your mappings to what it was before you changed it. The `<localleader>` expands when the mapping is defined, and will keep that also if you change `maplocalleader` afterward, but perhaps you already know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only a delay when there's actually an (insert mode) mapping defined. Use

```
:verbose imap <Space>
```

to hunt for the mapping(s) and which plugin defines it.